# Как через один интерфейс обращаться к нескольким шлюзам через swich

Tags: сеть, debian, proxy, шлюз

Встал такой вопрос, есть приложение 3proxy которое обращается к определенному IP и выходит через него в интернет

Связка следующая
Есть два интерфейса
enp47s0 - основной интернет на сервер, его не трогаем

enp37s0 - интерфейс с выходом на свич, к которому подключены два 3g модема

```
192.168.101.1
192.168.102.1
```

Адреса, модемы пингуются

Нужно что бы при обращении к 192.168.101.101 шлюз по умолчанию был 192.168.101.1
и для 192.168.102.101 соответственно 192.168.102.1

пробовал давать роуты

```
192.168.101.101 192.168.101.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp37s0
192.168.102.101 192.168.102.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp37s0
```

не проходит

так же как и выставлять два интерфейса со своим шлюзом

```
auto enp37s0
allow-hotplug enp37s0
iface enp37s0 inet static
        address 192.168.101.101
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        gateway 192.168.101.1

iface enp37s0 inet static
        address 192.168.102.101
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        gateway 192.168.102.1
```

Нечего не работает :(

upd. Главная цель добавить N количество интерфейсов, который будет иметь свой шлюз, в сетях слабо разбираюсь, не могу понять как.

Пробовал даже бриджы создавать

```
    auto br0
    iface br0 inet static
            address 192.168.101.101
            network 192.168.101.0
            netmask 255.255.255.0
            broadcast 192.168.101.255
            gateway 192.168.101.1
            bridge_ports enp37s0
            bridge_stp off
            bridge_fd 0
            bridge_maxwait 0

auto br1
    iface br1 inet static
            address 192.168.102.101
            network 192.168.102.0
            netmask 255.255.255.0
            broadcast 192.168.102.255
            gateway 192.168.102.1
            bridge_ports enp37s0
            bridge_stp off
            bridge_fd 0
            bridge_maxwait 0
```

Comment: А какие ip у вас подняты на интерфейсе в сторону свитча и по какому ip вот те 2 модема видят вашу машину. А еще надо что бы вот те машины 101.101 и 102.101 понимали, что тот адрес с которого вы к ним приходите, находится для них за модемом

Comment: на интерфейсе в сторону свича подняты два IP 192.168.101.101 и 192.168.102.101, два модема обычные не прошитые тп линки 3g, если выставить gateway не 192,168,0,1 - enp47s0 по которому приходит основной интернет, а любой из модемов 192.168.101.1 или 192.168.102.1 то все работает.

Comment: так, стоп. из вашего вопроса следует что 101.101 и 102.101 подняты не на вашей машине. Или фраза "Нужно что бы при обращении к ..." обозначала что кто то обращается с произвольного ip по вашему адресу 101.101 и 102.101 ? И вам при этом надо что бы ответные пакеты от вас уходили нужным маршрутом

Comment: Так, теперь понятней стало. Просто роуты ваши запутали, потому как в роутер пишется адрес на который должна обращаться ваша машина что бы пойти по этому маршруту, а не с которого она это делает.

Comment: ну да, добавлю так же: есть интерфейс enp37s0 к которому подключен свич, в свиче может быть от 1 до 10 3g модемов, так вот, как получить с каждого модема ип?) пробовал по dhcp
iface enp37s0 inet dhcp получаю ип только одного модема

Comment: Через один неуправляемый свитч по dhcp более 1 адрса получить невозможно. Нужен тогда управляемый свитч, который притащит модемы с разных портов в ваш порт с разных тегированных vlan. Что бы ваша машина могла отличить их и можно было создать разнын vlan-интерфейсы, на которых уже запускать dhcp клиента. Так что для неуправляемого свитча только статикой писать как сейчас

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поднимайте интерфесы так, как сочтете нужным, главное что бы адреса модемов 101.1 и 102.1 пинговались. При описании интерфейсов шлюзы указывать не надо. (потому как шлюз по умолчанию может быть только один) После этого вам надо создать несколько таблиц маршрутизации, в каждую из которых положить свой маршрут по умолчанию. И после этого написать правила условной маршрутизации, говорящие о том в каком случае этими таблицами пользоваться. Это можно сделать примерно так:

```
ip route add default tab 101 via 192.168.101.1  # маршрут по умолчанию в таблицу 101
ip route add default tab 102 via 192.168.102.1  # маршрут по умолчанию в таблицу 102

ip rule add prio 101 from 192.168.101.101 lookup 101
# При уходе пакета с исходящего адреса 101.101 использовать таблицу маршрутизации 101
ip rule add prio 102 from 192.168.102.101 lookup 102
# При уходе пакета с исходящего адреса 102.101 использовать таблицу маршрутизации 102
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)) 3 дня мучался с этим))))

Comment: ах вот почему рулями, а не метриками)

Comment: @eri На сколько я понимаю (и вы это в своем ответе пишите) "работает шлюз с наименьшей метрикой". Но задача в том, что бы для определенных групп пакетов работал конкретный шлюз. Т.е. в одно и то же время одно соединение должно идти через один, а другое через другой.

Comment: это где-то в коментариях... ответ добавил для полноты картины, а не потому что  считаю его самым правильным.

Comment: тут ещё есть варианты с мультипутем и с неймспейсами) от задачи зависит.
rule from подходят для серверов, но не очень хорошо работают с клиентами и форвардом

Comment: @eri На самом деле в самом вопросе, но сразу в глаза не бросается. там фраза "_Нужно что бы при обращении к 192.168.101.101 шлюз по умолчанию был 192.168.101.1 и для 192.168.102.101 соответственно 192.168.102.1_" я думаю оно должно было бы звучать "_Нужно, что бы при ответе ОТ 192.168.101.101 использовался шлюз 101.1, а при ответе ОТ 102.101 шлюз 102.1_". И походу тут задача именно с сервером, который разбрасывает запросы через несколько исходящих интернет каналов

Comment: и модемы тут не очень вписываются)

Answer (score 0):

Для записи нескольких конфигураций на один интерфейс создается алиас.

Алиас задается через `:`:

```
auto enp37s0:1
auto enp37s0:2

iface enp37s0:1 inet static
        address 192.168.101.101
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.101.1
        metric 10

iface enp37s0:2 inet static
        address 192.168.102.101
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.102.1
        metric 20
```

Можно добавлять несколько шлюзов с разной метрикой. Работает шлюз с наименьшей метрикой. Маски лучше не пересекать - в этом случае /24 а не /16